Why does SwiftData hang when using a predicate?
For some reason, when using a predicate, my app freezes and hangs. It works fine with just @Query private var items: [Item]
If you use the following arguments when running the app:

-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1

you can see that SwiftData is doing something, as there is a lot of activity in the logs.
Please find the full code attached. You can copy it to reproduce this freeze.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Item: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var flag = false
    
    init(name: String, flag: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.flag = flag
    }
}


struct SharedModelContainer {
    
    static var container: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
}


@main
struct FocusedProjectApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                HomeView()
            }
        }
        .modelContext(ModelContext(SharedModelContainer.container))
    }
}


struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var showDebug = false
    @State private var showSettings = false

    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()

//     hangs when using a predicate
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> { item in
        !item.flag
    }) var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            if items.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView("No items", systemImage: "trash")
            } else {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink {
                    SettingsView()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("test") private var test: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}


One of the solutions is either to not use the predicate or not use AppStorage. Of course, these fix the freeze but do not address the root cause. Additionally, I've had similar issues with @Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss and similar property wrappers.

In your main app replace the modelContext modifier with the modelContainer modifier

@JoakimDanielson Doesn't change anything.

Ok but still, that is the way you should do it even if it wasn't the cause of your error.

@JoakimDanielson This is actually pretty similar to what Apple did in their Backyard tutorial. Is there any difference?

Well you have a point because when I look at the documentation for the two modifiers it's almost identical but in all examples I have seen the modelContainer modifier is used and this goes for the Backyard Bird project as well (at least the version I have on my computer)
